# Swift - Dictionary with array of tuples

Tags: ios, swift

<strike>I am trying to create a list to hold the data for a tableview with sections.</strike>

I would like to use it like that:

```
cell.NameLabel.text = list[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name
```

**Edited**

I tried to make the question simple because english is not my main language.
let me try to ask the right question:

I would like to create a dictionary with array of tuples
Something like that:

```
var myDict = Dictionary<Array<(code: String, type:  String)>>()
```

And I would like to access like that:

```
myDict["blue"][0].type
```

Comment: Go right ahead. What's the problem? It looks like an array of arrays. So?

Comment: This has to take the record for worst question.

Comment: sorry for the wrong question. I did update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of `myDict` in your example is wrong, because a `Dictionary` requires the type of the keys and the type of the values. You should declare it as:

```
var myDic = Dictionary<String, Array<(code: String, type:  String)>>()
```

Then, you can use it (almost) as you wanted to:

```
myDic["one"] = [(code: "a", type: "b")]
myDic["two"] = [(code: "c", type: "d"), (code: "e", type: "f")]

let t = myDic["two"]![0].type
...
```

Note the `!` after the `myDic["two"]`. Thats because accessing a `Dictionary` by key returns an `Optional`, you need to unwrap it first.

Actually, this code would be better:

```
if let item: Array<(code: String, type:  String)> = myDic["two"] {
    let t = item[0].type
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you know How can I append values in this dict?
I did try with:

myDic["one"][0] = (code: "a", type: "b")

and

myDic["one"].append(code: "a", type: "b")

Comment: @ricardo, that's another question :) You need to assign the `item` above to an auxiliary variable, append to that variable and then put that variable in the dictionary. If that's no clear enough please post it as a new question.

Comment: I did that. I as I am new to swift, I was thinking why the .append does not work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, this would be a very simple Array of Array of an object. I invite you to read the Apple Language Reference of Swift about collections and Arrays : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

```
import UIKit

class Object {
    var name: String

    init(string: String) {
        name = string
    }
}

var objects: [[Object]] = [[Object]]()

for section in 0..<3 {
    for i in 0..<10 {
        objects[section][i] = Object(string: "My Object \(section) \(i)")
    }
}

let myString = objects[2][1].name
```